# Navbar dropdown not overflowing out of the navbar container

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have created a navbar using tailwind. I needed to add a dropdown in the navbar. The dropdown works fine but it does not escape the navbar container and kind of hides under it.

[image]

I want the dropdown to exceed the container and overflow.

Here is my Navbar code:

```
<header className="bg-[#182038]">
      <nav className="max-w-wt 2xl:max-w-ft mx-auto">
        <Container className="relative z-50 sm:z-0 flex justify-between py-4 sm:py-2 drop-shadow-2xl  ">
          <div className="relative z-10 sm:z-0 flex items-center gap-16 px-0">
            <Link to="/" aria-label="Home">
              <img
                className="object-contain w-36 md:w-56"
                src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBaP.png"
                alt="Workflow"
              />
            </Link>
            <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-10">
              {checkAuth && <NavLinks />}
              {!checkAuth && <ProNavLinks />}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
            <Popover className="lg:hidden">
              {({ open }) => (
                <>
                  <Popover.Button
                    className="relative z-10 inline-flex items-center rounded-lg "
                    aria-label="Toggle site navigation"
                  >
                    {({ open }) =>
                      open ? (
                        <XIcon
                          className="block h-6 w-6 text-white"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <MenuIcon
                          className="block h-6 w-6 text-white"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                      )
                    }
                  </Popover.Button>
                  <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
                    {open && (
                      <>
                        <Popover.Overlay
                          static
                          as={motion.div}
                          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                          className="fixed inset-0 z-0 bg-gray-600/60 backdrop-blur"
                        />
                        <Popover.Panel
                          static
                          as={motion.div}
                          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -32 }}
                          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                          exit={{
                            opacity: 0,
                            y: -32,
                            transition: { duration: 0.2 },
                          }}
                          className="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 z-0 origin-top rounded-b-2xl bg-[#182038] px-6 pb-6  pt-32 shadow-2xl shadow-gray-900/20"
                        >
                          <div className="space-y-4 text-white">
                            <MobileNavLink to="/">Home</MobileNavLink>
                            <MobileNavLink to="/cex-activity">
                              CEX Activity
                            </MobileNavLink>
                            <MobileNavLink to="/dex-activity">
                              DEX Activity
                            </MobileNavLink>
                            <MobileNavLink to="/trending">
                              Trending
                            </MobileNavLink>
                            <MobileNavLink to="/ranking">Ranking</MobileNavLink>
                            <MobileNavLink to="/pricing">Pricing</MobileNavLink>
                          </div>
                          <div className="mt-8 flex flex-col gap-4">
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="  p-1 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white border px-2 border-[#B0EEFD]"
                              onClick={props.handleLoginClick}
                            >
                              Login
                            </button>

                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="bg-[#B0EEFD] px-3 py-1 rounded text-white hover:text-white"
                              onClick={props.handleRegisterClick}
                            >
                              Register
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </Popover.Panel>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </AnimatePresence>
                </>
              )}
            </Popover>
            {auth ? (
              <>
                {user?.fullname && (
                  // <p className="text-white text-xs">Hello {user?.fullname}!</p>
                  <Menu as="div" className="ml-3 relative">
                    <div>
                      <Menu.Button className="bg-gray-800 flex text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
                        <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                        <img
                          className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </Menu.Button>
                    </div>
                    <Transition
                      as={Fragment}
                      enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                      enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                      enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                      leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                      leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                      leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    >
                      <Menu.Items className="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none ">
                        <Menu.Item>
                          {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                              href="/"
                              className={classNames(
                                active ? "bg-gray-100" : "",
                                "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"
                              )}
                            >
                              Your Profile
                            </a>
                          )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item>
                          {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                              href="/"
                              className={classNames(
                                active ? "bg-gray-100" : "",
                                "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"
                              )}
                            >
                              Settings
                            </a>
                          )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item>
                          {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                              href="/"
                              className={classNames(
                                active ? "bg-gray-100" : "",
                                "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"
                              )}
                            >
                              Sign out
                            </a>
                          )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                      </Menu.Items>
                    </Transition>
                  </Menu>
                )}

                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white"
                  onClick={props.handleLogout}
                >
                  Logout
                </button>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="hidden sm:block p-1 rounded-md text-[#B0EEFD] border px-2 border-[#B0EEFD]"
                  onClick={props.handleLoginClick}
                >
                  Login
                </button>

                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="bg-[#B0EEFD] px-3 py-1 rounded text-black hover:text-black hidden sm:block "
                  onClick={props.handleRegisterClick}
                >
                  Register
                </button>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </Container>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

How can I fix this issue? Is there an issue with overflow? There is no overflow property in the navbar which would make me believe it is that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `z-10` to the root `Menu` tag. This will lift it up to the top.

Comment: Z index did not work. I think the issue is that it is not moving out of the navbar container